# Equivalent to JDIC?

Tags: java, jdic, desktop-integration

Apart from [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net), does anyone know a project working towards desktop/Java integration?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the features of JDIC have been integrated in the JDK now (see the Desktop and SystemTray classes in the java.awt package)

The DJ Project on SourceForge keeps on developing desktop components such as a native browser for Swing:

http://djproject.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at nativeswing project
http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/